# how to run kafka from docker landoop image

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have updated my windows OS 10 from Home to Pro. I have installed windows docker toolbox on my machine.

I try to run the apache kafka in docker using following command :

```
docker run --rm -it \
    -p 2181:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 8081:8081 \
    -p 8082:8082 -p 8083:8083 -p 9092:9092 \
    -e ADV_HOST=192.168.99.100 \
    landoop/fast_data_dev
```

But when I run the above program, it gives me following error :

Unable to find image 'landoop/fast_data_dev:latest' locally
F:...\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: repository landoop/fast_data_dev not found: does not exist or no pull access.

See:'F:...\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help.

Please let me know what is the problem over here.

Comment: Spelling mistake the correct docker image name is `landoop/fast-data-dev`

Answer (score 2):

The image name appears to be incorrect. I think you are looking for https://hub.docker.com/r/landoop/fast-data-dev/. The correct command should be (notice the `-` instead of `_`):

```
docker run --rm -it -p 2181:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 -p 8083:8083 -p 9092:9092 -e ADV_HOST=192.168.99.100 landoop/fast-data-dev
```